# Assign 'active' class only to deepest child

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap-based < UL > navigation tree where every < LI > in the path to the current page is given the class "active". So if I was on a page two levels below the homepage, the code would be roughly like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link1</li>
  <li>Link2</li>
  <li class='active'>Link3
    <ul>
      <li>sublink1</li>
      <li class=active>sublink2
        <ul>
          <li>subsublink1</li>
          <li class=active>subsublink2 THIS IS MY PAGE</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

The problem is that bootstrap adds a border to all li.active elements. And I only want the border to apply to the deepest one, i.e., the page I'm actually on.

I'm not going to mess with the bootstrap underpinnings, so I'm not going to remove the active class from the whole path.

My goal is to have jQuery remove the unwanted borders. I want to find any li.active with no children that are li.active, which indicates it's the deepest li.active in the path. Then find all its parents with li.active and remove the border from them.

HOW WOULD I CONSTRUCT THAT JQUERY?

I'm thinking something like this (knowing that notHasClass doesn't exist):

```
$('li.active').children().notHasClass('active').parents.hasClass('active').css('border','none');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find all `li.active` elements which contain another `.active` element and remove the border:

```
$('li.active:has(.active)').css({ border : 'none' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8K4E/

Comment: nice, very simple.  +1 from me

Comment: You win , very elegant

Comment: @Heraldmonkey of course you can replace `.css(...)` with `.addClass('hasSubMenu')` and use CSS to get rid of the borders, as suggested in your comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/17830013/4879

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$("li.active").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("li.active").length>0){
        $(this).css("border","none");
    }
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DDUNE/
Or i didn't understand you right?

Comment: This does get the job done, but I used pawel since it was more concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With :last u get the last element in the DOM. So you can get the parents with li.active and remove the border.

```
$('li.active:last').parents('li.active').css('border', 'none');
```

Check out the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmgUh/

Alternatively u can replace .css('border', 'none') with removeClass('active').

Best regards

Comment: is `last` looking in depth?

Comment: If you mean in depth of the hole DOM: yes. Take a look at the jquery page: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `li` can only have `ul` as its children and that only `li` will have `.active` class, and for these assumptions, this works:

```
$('li.active').filter( function () {
    if ( $(this).children('ul').length === 0 )
        return true;
    return false;
}).parents('li').removeClass('active');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/ad5Zu/)

Answer (score 0):

found a slightly different way to achieve it:

```
$('li.active').has('ul').addClass('hasSubmenu');
```

Obviously if my li contains a ul it can't be the deepest li.active.

So now I can use pure css to get rid of the border:

```
li.active.hasSubmenu {border:none}
```

Comment: It is exactly what @pawel posted , be kind and accept his answer

Comment: this wouldn't work as it may have a ul but that ul may not have an active li in it

Comment: @Pete you're right but in my specific case only active sub ULs are displayed, so it would work.